# How to shorten dot product

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis, quadratics

I would like to shorten a dot/scalar product:
$$f(s)=sP_1+s^2P_2+\big((P_2-P_1)^TsN_1\big)N_1$$ Here $s$ are scalars, $P$ are points and $N$ are unit normal vectors in $R^3$. The function $f(s)$ returns a point. Of course $$(P_2-P_1)^TsN_1$$ is a dot product. How can I rewrite the equation to show it is a quadratic function e.g. in polynomial form? That is why I would like to rewrite the dot product.

Comment: Do you need something more than simply moving $s$ to the left of that term? What remains is the projection of $P_2-P_1$ onto $N_1$ which, presumably is constant in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Now I can see how to get $s$ out and get to: $f(s)=sP_1+s\big((P_2-P_1)^TN_1\big)N_1+s^2P_2$. But how to combine $sP_1$ and $s\big((P_2-P_1)^TN_1\big)N_1$?

Comment: Ok, I got it: $s(P_1+...N_1)+s^2P_2$. Thank you very much.